# strstr() function returns the address 0x0000

Tags: c, avr

I'm trying to check whether (and where) a substring ("DATA") is located in a big string (located in a buffer - linearBuffer) by strstr() function, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why eventhough my source string (located in the linearBuffer) in null terminated.

What really happended is that a ringbuffer (buf) fills with characters for every USART interrupt. Then, in some point of the code its content copied into a linear buffer (through ringBuff_to_linearBuff()) and I apply the strstr() function on it in order to find a wanted substring. The value that I get when the function strstr() returns is the value 244 and not the location of the substring eventhough I know its there from setting a breakpoint

** Note that my code is spread on many files so I tried to gather all question related code together.

```
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE           400
#define LINEAR_BUFFER_SIZE (BUFFER_SIZE+1)
#define WIFI_CMD_DATA   "DATA"

typedef RingBuff_Data_t        uint8_t;

typedef struct
{
    RingBuff_Data_t  Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; /**< Internal ring buffer data, referenced by the buffer pointers. */
    RingBuff_Data_t* In; /**< Current storage location in the circular buffer */
    RingBuff_Data_t* Out; /**< Current retrieval location in the circular buffer */
} RingBuff_t;

volatile RingBuff_t buf;
uint8_t linearBuffer[LINEAR_BUFFER_SIZE]="";

static inline void RingBuffer_Insert(RingBuff_t* const Buffer, const RingBuff_Data_t Data)
{
    *Buffer->In = Data;

    if (++Buffer->In == &Buffer->Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE])
              Buffer->In = Buffer->Buffer;

    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
    {
        Buffer->Count++;
    }
}

ISR(USART1_RX_vect)
{
    //code to be executed when the rx pin of the USART receives a char
    uint8_t c = UDR_N;
    if (c != '\n')
        RingBuffer_Insert(&buf,c);
    else
        RingBuffer_Insert(&buf,'\0');
}

void ringBuff_to_linearBuff(uint8_t linearBuffer[])
{
    memset(linearBuffer,0,LINEAR_BUFFER_SIZE);
    RingBuff_Data_t* tempIn = buf.In;
    if (buf.Out < tempIn){
        memcpy(linearBuffer, buf.Out, tempIn - buf.Out);
    }
    else if (buf.Out > tempIn){
        size_t s1 = buf.Buffer + BUFFER_SIZE - buf.Out;
        size_t s2 = buf.In - buf.Buffer;
        memcpy(linearBuffer, buf.Out, s1);
        memcpy(linearBuffer + s1, buf.Buffer, s2);
    }
}

void main () 
{
    uint8_t* linearBufferp;
    while (1)
    {
        if (buf.Out != buf.In)
        {
            ringBuff_to_linearBuff(linearBuffer);
            linearBufferp = strstr(linearBuffer, WIFI_CMD_DATA); // Checking if a new DATA msg from a client had arrived
            if (linearBufferp != NULL)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Barc0.png)

Comment: Why are you using `uint8_t` array to store strings? Anyway, it would be better adding a `printf("%s\n", linearBuffer);` before the call to `strstr`, so that we can make sure it's there.

Comment: It's hard for us to help since the code is incomplete. For example, we don't know whether `Buffer->In` and `Buffer->Out` are correctly initialised. And we don't know the invocations of `ISR` and whether it really completed the NUL termination before `ringBuff_to_linearBuff` was called.

Comment: What  is `linearBufferp`?

Comment: How does the code make sure all those `memcpy(linearBuffer, ...`s so not write past the end of the allocated memory to where `linearBuffer,` points to?

Comment: "*returns is the value `244` ...*" how do you know this, does the code log this? Which statement prints the `244`?

Comment: alk, I edited the code. linearBufferp is a pointer to uint8_t which holds the address of the first occurence of the wanted substring in the big string.
The statement which "prints" it is  linearBufferp = strstr(linearBuffer, WIFI_CMD_DATA); , I set a breakpoint there...

Comment: kaylum, I understand what you say but I really made effort to gather what's really important for the question (the code is too big).
anyway, I have this statement : RingBuffer_InitBuffer(&buf); at the beginning of the code which set both Buffer->In and Buffer->out to Buffer->Buffer.

Comment: For minimal debugging (not fixing) purpose make sure `linearBuffer` gets `0`-terminated by adding `linearBuffer[LINEAR_BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';` as last statement to `ringBuff_to_linearBuff()` and retest.

Comment: @Prince777 I can see that you have tried. But it doesn't change the fact that we can't debug what we can't see. So if you can't create a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then there is a chance you won't get an answer as the problem may not even be in the code you have shown.

Comment: Not to be rude but there is no way `strstr` will return 224 if that isn't the location of the substring. You must be interpreting something in the wrong way. Why don't you print the pointer values? And show us the code where `linearBufferp` prints the value 224.

Comment: @4386427: Well, if UB had been invoke prior to "printing" the pointer value this might very well result in 42... ;-)

Comment: @alk - Good point. I still like to see a proof of that value. I think OP doesn't read the debugger values correct. But again - you are right.

Comment: I think the problem is that you use uint8_t as datatype for linearBufferp, as eight bits may not be enough to store the whole memory address.

Comment: @Xaver, 8 bits = byte = char. Am I not rignt ?

Comment: I attached a debugging pic from a point in time so you can see what in the linearbuffer and what value the linearbufferp is having. I would be glad if it would point to address 0x066d (linearBuffer [14]) so it would hold "68" = D
 but instead it points to 0x0000 and it has the value of 224 :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `strstr` returns NULL it means that it didn't find the substring (and when that happens, the value it points to have no meaning at all, so forget about the 224).

So your question should be:

> Why doesn't strstr find my substring?

When looking at the debug picture you posted, your `linearBuffer`contains:

```
13
 0
13
 0
43
....
....
68      <---- This is what you want to find
65
....
```

However, there are multiple strings in your buffer:

```
13     <----- Start of first string
 0     <----- End of first string
13     <----- Start of second string
 0     <----- End of second string
43     <----- Start of thrid string
....
....
68      <---- This is what you want to find
65
....
```

`strstr` will only search the first string. When `strstr` sees the first `0` (index [1]), it returns `NULL` because it didn't find what it was looking for.

In other words - `strstr` never looks at the part of the buffer where the match is. It returns long before that.

> So what's wrong with your code?

It is hard to say since you haven't posted a complete code base. So this is a guess. I think you receive a number of "newlines" in the form:

```
13 10 13 10
```

before the message. So you receive:

```
13 10 13 10 43 ...... 68 65 .....
```

Your ISR turns the `10` into `0` so the buffer becomes

```
13 0 13 0 43 ...... 68 65 .....
```

which is 3 strings instead of 1 string.

> What to do?

Well, there could be several different solutions. The correct depends on your system requirements. A simple solution would be to skip the extra `13 0` before calling `strstr`. Something like:

```
ringBuff_to_linearBuff(linearBuffer);
// Skip "13 0"
while (*linearBuffer == 13 && *(linearBuffer+1) == 0)
{
    linearBuffer += 2;
}
linearBufferp = strstr(linearBuffer, WIFI_CMD_DATA);
```

Note: You should add some range check also so that `linearBuffer` isn't incremented so much that you read out of bounds